# Linear combination of posterior g.p.d.f

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Suppose that each of $k$ statisticians has his own prior distribution for a certain
parameter $\theta$, and let $f_{i}$ be the g.p.d.f. which statistician $i$ assigns to $\theta$, $i = 1, ..., k$.
Suppose also that an executive forms his opinion about $\theta$ from the opinions of the $k$
statisticians and that he assigns to $\theta$ the g.p.d.f. $f^{*}$ defined, at each point $\theta \in \Theta$, as follows:

$$f^{*}(\theta) = \alpha_{1}f_{1}(\theta)\ + ... +\ \alpha_{k}f_{k}(\theta)$$

Here $\alpha_{1},\ ...,\ \alpha_{k}$ are weights such that $\alpha_{i} \geq 0$, $i = 1, ..., k$, and $\alpha_{1} +...+\alpha_{k} = 1$. The value of $α_{i}$ reflects the relative weight that the executive gives to the opinion of statistician $i$.
Suppose further that the $k$ statisticians and the executive observe together the value of a
random variable $X$ whose conditional g.p.d.f., given $\theta$, is $f(·|\theta)$. Show that the posterior g.p.d.f. of the executive will again be a linear combination of the posterior g.p.d.f.’s of the $k$ statisticians, with new weights $\beta_{1}, ..., \beta_{k}$ which will depend on the observed value of $X$. Also, discuss the conditions under which the weight $\beta_{1}$ in the posterior g.p.d.f. will be greater than the weight $\alpha_{1}$ in the prior g.p.d.f.

**Attempt:**

By the Bayes theorem, we have:

$$f(\theta|X) = \frac{f(X|\theta)f(\theta)}{\int_{\Theta} f(x|\theta ')f(\theta ') d\theta'} \propto f(X|\theta)f(\theta)$$

Thus,

$$f_{i}(\theta|X) \propto f(X|\theta)f_{i}(\theta)$$

See that

\begin{align}
f^{*}(\theta|X) \propto f(X|\theta) f^{*}(\theta) &= f(X|\theta) [\alpha_{1}f_{1}(\theta) + ... + \alpha_{k}f_{k}(\theta)]\\
&= \alpha_{1}f(X|\theta)f_{1}(\theta) + ... + \alpha_{k}f(X|\theta)f_{k}(\theta)\\
& \propto \beta_{1}f_{1}(\theta|X) + ... + \beta_{k}f_{k}(\theta|X)
\end{align}

Then the posterior g.p.d.f of the executive is linear combination of the posterior g.p.d.f's of the $k$ statisticians.
My attempt is correct? Someone can help to solve the second question about the weight $\beta_{1}$?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does "g.p.d.f" mean?

Comment: @kimchi lover, sorry, it's a term used in Degroot's book, but you can consider a pdf (probability density function)

Comment: I repeat, what do the letters "g.p.d.f." mean?

Comment: @kimchi lover, its generalized probability density function

Comment: Thank you.  And exactly what is a "generalized probability density function"?

Comment: well, this is the explanation in the book: "It is convenient to have terminology and notation that will make it pos sible to discuss discrete distributions and absolutely continuous distribu tions simultaneously. Accordingly, to designate a function f that may be either a p.d.f. or a p.f., we shall use the term generalized probability density function (abbreviated g.p.d.f.)."